# Call js function from within the footer

Tags: javascript, php

I have around a 30 page website. I have included a footer.php on every document. Every fourth page I have, has some different js scripts in the footer. That's starting to annoy me, and I am thinking of making a script folder where I have small scripts in. Is that a bad idea instead of having them directly in the footer?

This is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        $('.bxslider1').bxSlider({
          minSlides: 5,
          maxSlides: 6,
          slideWidth: 360,
          slideMargin: 2,
          moveSlides: 1,
          responsive: true,
          nextSelector: '#slider-next',
          prevSelector: '#slider-prev',
          nextText: 'Onward →',
          prevText: '← Go back'
        });

      });
</script>
```

If I save this in a js folder under "bannerslider.js", how can I call the function from the footer? Do I have to include, or echo the file?

Comment: That's a very good idea. Just include the script in your page. `<script src="path/to/bannerslider.js"></script>`. Anytime you find yourself repeating code, it's always a good idea to put it in a single function/module/file.

Comment: a script tag will load and execute the javascript inside the file.  You don't need <script> tags around the code when the file is in a separate file like bannerslide.js.  You aren't defining any functions, you are just calling ready() and that will execute as soon as that script tag has loaded the file.  If you defined a function, it would be available globally or it would be attached to the window object (kind of the same thing in the browser).

Comment: Thank you a lot for the comments. I will take that in mind, that when I start repeating code, I will save the code in a function, and then call them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include the external js script(bannerslider.js) via `<script>` tag, but make sure that `bxSlider` plugin script was loaded previously.
An exemplary markup(replace `<YOUR-JS-FOLDER>` phrase with the name of your actual js folder):

```
<footer>
 ...
   <script type="text/javascript" src="<YOUR-JS-FOLDER>/bannerslider.js"></script>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. It works perfectly, and I can clean up my code. Nice feeling :-)

Comment: @McDuck4, you're welcome

Comment: Ops just one last question I came to think off. I call my footer.php on all my 30 pages. In my footer I have the references to JS and CSS. That means that all pages actually gonna have some references that is not used. Is that a problem?

Comment: if there are many external scripts which are included in "shared" footer and they have a large amount of code, which is unnecessary on some pages - I would create different layouts depending on crucial sections of your application. For instance, let's imagine that we have a `layout` folder with `main.php`, `news.php` and `profile.php` (layouts). Each layout should contain its own version of `<header>`, `content(body)` and `footer` section. `<footer>` in each layout can have different set of js scripts

Comment: Thank you again :)